# Interpreting meaning of "Cauchy series" (not sequence)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to prove that some particular infinite *series* is Cauchy. Of course, I know [what it means for a *sequence* to be Cauchy](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyCriterion.html), but I can't seem to find anything related to Cauchy series. Could someone help me to interpret the meaning of this?

Maybe it means that the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy?

Comment: Actually I would have thought that "Cauchy series" was more common than "Cauchy sequence"!  In any case, a series, $\sum a_n$ is a "Cauchy series" if and only if the sequence is a "Cauchy sequence".  In particular that means that the double sequence $|a_m- a_n|$ goes to 0 as m and n go to infinity independently.

Comment: @user247327 When you refer to "the sequence," I'm not sure which sequence you're referring to.  My expectation is that a series is a "Cauchy series" if the sequence of its partial sums is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you assumed, a series is Cauchy if the sequence of its partial sums is a Cauchy sequence.